# Storing tweets with different keywords. Single massive table, or one table for each keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, twitter

I'm going to be using the twitter streaming API to set up a truly live stream by pushing the tweets into a SQL database as they come in, then pull from my database as often as I want. This will allow me to somewhat get around the rate limiting, without getting myself blacklisted. [I found this method here.](http://blog.corunet.com/twitter-alerts-using-twitter-streaming-api/)

I'll be tracking several keywords in the stream (no more than 15)

> stream.twitter.com/whatever?q=word1 OR word2 OR word3 OR ...

As I'm storing these, would it be best to dump them all into one large table, or piece them out by keyword? I'm not sure if it comes down to preference, or if one way is better than the other.

I think ultimately it comes down to preprocessing them to put them into the correct keyword table, or post processing them from the massive table to pick the ones where keyword = "word1" etc.

Any thoughts as to which would be better from an optimization standpoint?

Comment: one table for each keyword??? do you have any idea how many keywords can you have?.  I would say a HUGE Massive table with the proper engine, index, data type than 1000+ different tables for each keyword

Comment: Likely no more than 15. Probably fewer than 10.

Comment: @jcho360 I think you might have misinterpreted his intent. Correct me if I'm wrong, Jon, but do you mean you'll only be tracking 15 or fewer keywords, each of these keywords would have their own table--making the maximum table count 15, and their row entries containing the tweet contents themselves?  If so, 15 tables is not entirely too many, though it still is not desirable.  A single table with partitioning should be able to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Hex, your interpretation is correct. I think I'll go with a single partition. Should work out just fine. Thanks for your input and clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not separate tables for each keyword.

If you want to go the relational DB route, I would certainly recommend fewer tables with more indexes.  Not sure exactly what you want to do but a keyword table, posts table, and a keyword_post association table.

Comment: This would certainly be a straightforward and maintainable approach.